# Problema descriptografia

Tags: php, criptografia

Tenho uma sessão em MySQL com PHP de uma criptografia um pouco avançada em PHP usando *Sha512*, estou com problemas em reverte-la para descriptografar os dados.

```php
function gen_token($pass, $salt)
{
   $salt = strtolower($salt);
   $str = hash("sha512", $pass.$salt);
   $len = strlen($salt);
   print strtoupper(substr($str, $len, 17));
}
```

Exemplo:

```
gen_token("123456789", "thalys");
```

Saída de senha:

```
8B9C96128F1517479
```

Answer (score 1):

A ideia de um hash é que ele seja irreversível mesmo... Assim nem mesmo quem tem acesso ao banco de dados pode saber quais são as senhas dos usuários, apenas o hash das senhas.

Você deve rodar essa função novamente na senha digitada durante a tentativa de login e comparar com a saída da senha original gravada no banco.

Algo como:

```
if (gen_token($_POST['senha'], "thalys") == "8B9C96128F1517479")
    echo "senha correta!";
```